# huxtable() regression tables do not align on decimal

Tags: r, r-markdown

huxtable regression tables claim to align coefficients on the decimal point, but to my knowledge, when coefficients are marked with significance stars, this fails. Please note, in the example Please see:

```
library(wakefield)

df<-r_data_frame(n=100,age,r_series(n=100, likert, j=3, relate="+1_2"))
mod1<-lm(Likert_3~Likert_1+Likert_2+Age, data=df)

library(tidyverse)

library(huxtable)
huxreg(mod1, stars = c(`*`=0.05, `**`=0.01)) %>% 
set_align(., '.') %>% 
quick_docx()
```

Comment: not quite sure what the question is here?

Comment: Anyway, think you are correct for .docx files; I suspect this is a limitation of the underlying `flextable` library. Feel free to report a bug in the package.